# TikZ, cannot find graphdrawing library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I am on Mac Os 10.11.6, my TexLive distribution is the one of 2016.

I would like to draw [this](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/drawing-graphs.tex) graph and I need to use `graphdrawing` library from `tikz`, but I am not able to do this because I receive the following message:

> `I can't find file 'tikzlibrarygraphdrawing.code.tex'. \usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}`

My TeX Live installation is updated, I have checked in TeX Live Utility in order to update the `tikz` package. I am able to use other libraries from `tikz` package (as `graphs` one).

Comment: Are you compiling with lualatex?

Comment: Can you show the log-file of a small document loading the library?

Comment: @samcarter the problem is I am not compiling with lualatex. Sorry for my stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

The very first error message tells you what to do:

> Package pgf Error: You need to run LuaTeX to use the graph drawing library.